# Setting text of UITextField from caller view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a barcode scanner on one view, and after the user has scanned the barcode, the app takes them to another view (BoilerDetails) where the barcode text field has been pre-filled.

I understand that the viewcontroller is null when it hasn't come into view and I can'tchange the UITextField text directly. This so far has given me an error.. How can I fix this?

BarcodeScannerViewController.m

```
BoilerDetailsViewController *viewCtrl = [[BoilerDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[viewCtrl setBarcode:strBarcode];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];
```

BoilerDetailsViewController.h

```
@interface BoilerDetailsViewController : SubViewControllerBase
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *barcode;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *barcodeField;
- (void)setBarcode:(NSString*)strBarcode;
@end
```

BoilerDetailsViewController.m

```
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    self.barcode = strBarcode;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_barcodeField setText:self.barcode];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: add `self.barcodeField.text = strBarcode` inside `-setBarcode:` method

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    self.barcode = strBarcode;
}
```

I think that these strings give you infinite loop. According to your logic you should use:

```
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    self.barcodeField.text = strBarcode;
}
```

or

```
@syntesize barcode = _barcode;

-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    [_barcode autorelease];
    _barcode = [strBarcode retain] //in case of no ARC
}
```

Depends on what you want (store a string or set a label).

Answer (score 0):

you just have to synthesize the `barcode` and in ViewDidload just write this code `[_barcodeField setText:barcode];` and good to Go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is wrong

```
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    self.barcode = strBarcode;
}
```

`self.barcode = strBarcode;` itself calls the setter.

depending on your ios version you shud write:

```
//for ARC environment
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    _barcode = strBarcode;
}
//since default association in ARC is strong
```

before this do `@synthesize barcode = _barcode;`

```
//and for non-ARC environment, since your property is retain type
-(void)setBarcode:(NSString *)strBarcode
{
    if (_barcode != barcode) {
        [_barcode release];
        _barcode = [barcode retain];
    }
}
```

And you will be OK.